# Группировка после JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня вопрос несколько общего характера, но я дам лабораторный пример для наглядности. Вопрос относится к ситуации, когда мы хотим поджойнить результат группировки, но при этом использовать индекс в группируемой таблице.

**Пример:**

Есть таблицы table1 и table2

table1:

| col_1a_pk | col_1b |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 5 |
| d | 3 |

table2:

| col_2a_pk | col_2b_pk | col_2c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 3 |
| a | 2 | 4 |
| c | 1 | 3 |
| c | 2 | 2 |
| b | 1 | 1 |

Я хочу поджойнить table2 к table1, но я хочу получить сумму col_2c из таблицы table2, группируя по col_2a_pk и уже полученный результат джойнить к table1, используя для джойна первые столбцы. Что я хочу иметь в результате:

table_result:

| col_1a_pk | col_1b | sum_col_2c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 7 |
| c | 5 | 5 |
| d | 3 | NULL |
| b | 2 | 1 |

Для удобства, вот CTE:

```
WITH
table1 AS (
  SELECT 'b' col_1a_pk, 1 col_1b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' col_1a_pk, 2 col_1b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c' col_1a_pk, 5 col_1b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' col_1a_pk, 3 col_1b FROM DUAL
),
table2 AS (
  SELECT 'a' col_2a_pk, 1 col_2b_pk, 3 col_2c FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' col_2a_pk, 2 col_2b_pk, 4 col_2c FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c' col_2a_pk, 1 col_2b_pk, 3 col_2c FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c' col_2a_pk, 2 col_2b_pk, 2 col_2c FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' col_2a_pk, 1 col_2b_pk, 1 col_2c FROM DUAL
)
```

Как я могу это сделать?

**Вариант 1**:

Просто джойним таблицу и группируем результат джойна

```
SELECT t1.col_1a_pk
     , t1.col_1b  
     , SUM(t2.col_2c) AS sum_col_2c
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col_1a_pk = t2.col_2a_pk  
 GROUP BY t1.col_1a_pk
        , t1.col_1b;
```

Преимущества:

- Мы используем индекс для PK в присоединямой таблице table2 и не шарим вложенным циклом по всей таблице.

Недостатки:

- Мы должны выполнить группировку по всем остальным столбцам. А их может быть, скажем, под сотню. А некоторые иметь под собой выражения, а не просто имя столбца. А если даже делать внешний запрос чтобы выписать только алиасы, то это все-равно поиск и выковыривание по тексту сотни имен столбцов, а потом группировка по ним. Сначала размножили, а потом схлопнули - лишняя работа серверу.

**Вариант 2**

Делаем подзапрос перед джойном, в котором и группируем значения:

```
SELECT t1.col_1a_pk
     , t1.col_1b  
     , t2.sum_col_2c
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT col_2a_pk
                  , SUM(col_2c) sum_col_2c
               FROM table2
              GROUP BY col_2a_pk) t2 ON t1.col_1a_pk = t2.col_2a_pk;
```

Преимущества:

- Не нужно выковыривать имена всех столбцов из внешнего запрос и потом делать по ним группировку

Недостатки:

- Сперва происходит полная обработка table2, то есть сперва он находит сумму по col_2c для КАЖДОГО значения col_2a_pk, даже для тех, которые нам не нужны, т.к. они отсутствуют в table1. В ситуации, когда в table2 огромное количество строк, 99% из которых нам не потребуется, это значительная лишняя нагрузка на сервер.
- Невозможно использовать индекс для col_2a_pk при джойне к table1

**Вариант 3**

Делаем подзапросы прямо в селект листе

```
SELECT t1.col_1a_pk
     , t1.col_1b  
     , (SELECT col_2a_pk
             , SUM(col_2c) sum_col_2c
          FROM table2
         WHERE col_2a_pk = t1.col_1a_pk) AS sum_col_2c
  FROM table1 t1;
```

Ну или другая форма записи (хотя механически, как я понимаю, проихсодит тот же процесс)

```
SELECT t1.col_1a_pk
     , t1.col_1b  
     , t2.sum_col_2c
  FROM table1 t1
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(col_2c) sum_col_2c
                 FROM table2
                WHERE col_2a_pk = t1.col_1a_pk) t2
```

Преимущества:

- Мы используем индекс при обращении к table2
- Мы ищем результат группировки только для нужных строк

Недостатки:

- Происходит куча вызовов в table2 для каждой строки в table1

**Итог и вопрос**

Как ни странно, замена архитектуры запроса со второго на третий способ (с подзапросом в select-листе) в реальной задаче ускорил запрос в 5 раз, хотя казалось бы, подзапросы - практика довольно порочная. Тем не менее, каждый раз дергать таблицу table2 с единственным значением выглядит как нечто улучшаемое в плане производительности. Можно ли более элегантно решить эту задачу? Чтобы table2 знала все значения col_2a_pk, которые понадобятся (не обрабатывая все таблицу и пользуясь индексом), но при этом и не размножала строки в запросе перед джойном?

Comment: SQL - декларативный язык. Вы формулируете задачу, сервер сам решает, как её выполнить. И все Ваши рассуждения о том, что и как будет делать сервер для получения результата, яйца выеденного не стоят. Лучше изучите построенный план выполнения.

Comment: @Akina способность сервера к анализу ограничена. Как вы видите выше, все запросы дают одинаковый результ, т.е. "задача" перед сервером стоит одинаковая. Но работают они с разной скоростью в разной ситуации. Да и хинты серверу существуют именно для компенсации его способности к анализу. Я что-то не очень понял чем спровоцировал подобную грубость.

Comment: В третьем запросе у вас где группировка? Он у вас не может работать так же как первый. Для каждой строки таблицы вы выбираете одну строку из другой таблицы. У вас where  стоит по главному уникальному ключу- то есть там всегда одна и только одна запись. А в первом запросе есть группировка, да бесполезная - потому что опять же связь там 1 к 1 но sql честно тратит на нее время

Comment: *т.е. "задача" перед сервером стоит одинаковая.* Нет, задачи различаются. Скажем, во втором запросе вы явно требуете от сервера посчитать все суммы, в том числе и те, которые не имеют соответствия в первой таблице. Возможно, на этапе оптимизации это будет обнаружено, и сервер не станет делать ненужную работу, но возможно и нет. Очень правильно вы говорите, что ресурсы на анализ ограничены. Более того, ограничены ну очень жёстко. Сервер обычно вынужден решать задачу жадно. Отсюда и план не всегда оптимальный, а только близок к нему.

Comment: @Akina Тут значимо то, что вы понимаете под "задачей". "Желаемый результат" или "способ его достижения". Если первый (результат), то он одинаковый. Если второе (способ) то именно об этом и вопрос - есть несколько путей решения и поставлен открытый вопрос о более правильном пути. Постановке задачи перед сервером для достижения желаемого результата, если вам так удобнее.

Comment: @user453575457 Я добавил CTE с содержимом тестовых таблиц чтобы вы сами могли выполнить запросы и убедиться в одинковом результате. Обратите внимание на то, что в первой таблице PK состоит из одного столбца, а во второй - из двух.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов естественно что результаты одинаковые. Еще раз - у вас связь один-к-одному col_2a_pk = t1.col_1a_pk  - одной записи в первой таблице соответствует одна запись во второй. Ваше "обратите внимание там пк из двух" - это бессмысленный пк 1 к 1 (каждой цифре соответствует только одна буква и наоборот ) -  Ваша суммирование выполняется только по одной строке - и не имеет никакого смысла. Так же как и группировка в первом варианте. Бессмысленная группировка что она есть что ее нет - результат один - а нагрузка на сервер разная. Вы в первом случае гоняете лишний раз mysql.

Comment: @user453575457 Возможно мы смотрим с вами на разные таблицы, но соверешнно очевидно, что во второй таблице для двух случаев суммирование происходит по двум строкам (для a и с), а не только 1 к 1. Напоминаю, что это лабораторный пример и в боевой таблице суммирование может происходить не по двум строкам, а по двум сотням.

Comment: Если у вас по многу записей и на них вы выполняли эти запросы - как у вас суммирование происходит без группировки в данном примере?  (а сумма без группировки возможно только если там 1 к 1)
SUM(col_2c) sum_col_2c
          FROM table2
         WHERE col_2a_pk = t1.col_1a_pk

Comment: @user453575457 Я вижу вы запутались. Распутаться вы могли бы просто запустив скрипты выше. Смотрите, мы идём по таблице table1, там первый столбец - первичный ключ, значения в нем уникальны. Для каждого из этого значения мы заглядываем в таблицу table2, там этот столбец не уникален. Мы находим две строки, возвращаем сумму по нужному столбцу и переходим к следующей строке table1. Я не знаю как объяснить это на более базовом уровне.
p.s. Если вас смущает отсутствие конструкции GROUP BY, она там не нужна, поскольку в подзапросе находятся только нужные нам строки, относящиеся к строке в table1

Comment: *Тут значимо то, что вы понимаете под "задачей".* Задача - это то, что поставлено перед сервером для исполнения. То есть текст запроса. То, какую логику заложили в запрос, чтобы на выходе получился требуемый результат - это внешнее и серверу не известно. Эта часть работы полностью отдана программисту, и я её не рассматриваю. Сервер получает запрос и отдаёт результат - работа над получением результата по тексту запроса и есть "задача". Если сервер умён, и его построитель смог построить план, не выполняющий ненужной работы - ну честь ему и хвала. Если ресурсов хватит на то, чтобы понять.

Comment: В варианте 1 для чего нужна группировка по ``t1.col_1b`` ? Без нее запрос выглядел бы лучше и можно использовать индекс по ``col_1a_pk``, без дополнительной сортировки по col_1b. И вариант JOIN планировщик выберет самый лучший - по первому полю составного индекса в table2. Возможно, и производительность станет не хуже вариантов 2 и 3.

Comment: Если table1 в 100 раз меньше table2, как раз подзапрос будет выгоднее.

Comment: SQL - странная вещь, можно получить идеальный результат на тестовом стенде и ужасный на бою, наоборот реже, но тоже бывает. Как бы ни хотелось сказать: "тут все просто, вот вам готовое решение", но увы, всегда надо смотреть план выполнения конкретного запроса на конкретной БД и конкретных данных, и уже исходя из полученного плана выполнения оптимизировать "узкие" места. Да, есть ряд "порочных практик" в построении запросов, но даже они в некоторых случаях могут оказаться эффективнее "лучших практик", да редко, но тоже случается

Comment: @ValNik, это не реальная ситуация, а воссоздающая какую-то реальну. В реальности у нас не просто col_1b в датасете, к которому мы хотим приаттачить результат группировки в другой таблице, но и под 30 других столбцов (по каждому из которых потребуется группировка, если мы не хотим чтобы строки размножились после джойна к таблице со связью один ко многим и навешивании групповой функции на результат джойна.

Comment: @Akina, обсуждение именно лучшей стратегии написания запроса для такого вот примера. Это ж первый и радикально важный этап в улучшении производительности. Я ведь не просто так описал несколько. Если вам не интересно это рассматривать, ну окей что ж.

Comment: Ну Вы же не первый день на форумах! И прекрасно знаете, что если задаёте вопрос по оптимизации запроса, то следует привести полные DDL всех таблиц (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`), сведения о статистике данных в разрезе запроса (а ещё лучше - генератор тест-данных либо ссылку на online fiddle), планы выполнения запросов, и точную и полную постановку задачи, включая описание особых случаев. В опубликованном вопросе нет и половины - ну и с чем работать?

Comment: Мы рассматриваем описанную Вами ситуацию. В ней не видно необходимости группировки по дополнительным столбцам. Если у Вас таких столбцов много и по ним выполняются дополнительные группировки, куча сортировок - это отдельная задача, может быть более дорогая, чем присоединение table2. Как задали вопрос - так и отвечаем) Если table2 100 раз больше table1, применяйте подзапрос. При этом что делать с table1 - не имеет значения - все равно придется делать.

Comment: Все же, непонятно, какая может быть группировка после группировки по primary_key - ведь в группе будет точно одна строка. Не понятно.

Comment: @ValNik, давайте останемся в нашем примере. Вот вы сгруппировали по PK. Отлично, да, действительно сейчас каждой строке соответствует уникальный результат. Но ведь нам и table1.col_1b нужно отобразить в результате. Вы результат группировки по PK предлагаете джойнить еще раз на table1 чтобы отобразить остальные интересующие нас столбцы (col_1b в нашем случае)? А если это PK только по бизнес-логике, а не по архитектуре (с индексом)?

Comment: @ValNik А если вместо таблицы у нас подзапрос на 10 джойнов? Их тоже группировать и джойнить самих на себя (через CTE, например)? Проще ведь выполнить один джойн и добавить в группировку все интересующие столбцы. О том, что это является недостатком подхода я указал в описании.

Comment: Если провести группировку по PK и нужно сохранить значение table1.col_1b, пишите min(table1.col_1b) as col_1b. Дополнительных JOIN не нужно. PK по бизнес-логике или архитектуре - не так важно. Можно всегда сделать индекс по нему.

Comment: Поясните, все же, для чего нужна группировка по уникальному ключу??

Comment: @ValNik да я думаю, вы понимаете для чего - иначе просто запрос не выполнится, когда есть столбцы, не участвующие в группировке или групповой функции. Тут есть два стула - выполнить группировку или навесить функцию (у вас это min()).